# back transform before ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, transform

I want to back transforme my data (from the log10) before making the ggplot2, but don't know how to adjust this in the dfresids:

```
>data=read.csv("Observation Data 2014_sorted_stacked.csv")
data$TREATMENT=relevel(data$TREATMENT,ref="CONTROL")

>fit_a=lm(log10(TOTAL+1)~COLONY+TREATMENT*poly(DAY_SINCE_TREATMENT,2)+TIME_ORD+WEATHER,data=data) 

>eff_a=Effect(mod=fit_a,focal.predictors=c("DAY_SINCE_TREATMENT","TREATMENT"),partial.residuals=TRUE)

>dfeff=data.frame(eff_a) 
dfresids=data.frame(resids=exp(predict(fit_a,type="response")+eff_a$residuals), 
                eff_a$x.all)

>ggplot ??
```

`

Comment: This question does not seem specific to ggplot2. Best to perhaps move elsewhere?